# Pop up label on JVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, jvectormap

I am new to jQuery and have been developing a JVectorMap. I have created markers but I was wondering if anyone could help me with creating a pop up window or label that appears when one of the markers is clicked. This window/label will display information about the specific marker clicked.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve, if anyone could help me with this it would be much appreciated!

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the click event of a marker and get the text of the clicked marker.

[image]

```
<script>
    var markers = [
        { latLng: [48.921537, -66.829834], name: "One", text: "This is a text of one." },
        { latLng: [45.995944, -64.171143], name: "Two", text: "This is a text of two." }
    ];

    $(function () {
        $('#map').vectorMap({
            map: 'ca_lcc_en',
            markers: markers,
            onMarkerClick: function (e, index) {
                $('#text').text(markers[index].text);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="map" style="float: left; width: 400px; height: 400px;">
</div>
<div id="text" style="float: right; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;">
</div>
```